# What is the correct Java mapping of the shm_open function?

Tags: shared-memory, jna, glibc

I'm trying to write some JNA code that accesses glibc, specifically functions defined in `mmap.h`.

I have tried to define it exactly as shown in `man shm_open`. The `getuid()` function call just before it works, but `shm_open` doesn't return.

I'm constrained to using JNA 4.4.0 and JNA Platform 3.4.0.

```java
interface LibC extends Library {
    LibC INSTANCE = Native.loadLibrary("c", LibC.class);

    int shm_open(String name, int oFlag, int mode);
}
```

```java
// ...
int fileDescriptor = LibC.INSTANCE.shm_open("/some_memory.123", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
// ...
```

I expect a file descriptor to be returned, but I get these exceptions:

- When I load "libc.so.6": `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'shm_open': /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: undefined symbol: shm_open`
- When I load "c": `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'shm_open': /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: undefined symbol: shm_open`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I figured out the issue while writing the question.

While `getuid()` and friends are defined in `libc`, `shm_open` and friends are defined in `librt`. I really should have realized that because the manpage for `shm_open` explicitly states "Link with `-lrt`", indicating it residing in the "rt" lib.

In short: I need a new interface for LibRT alongside LibC, loaded with name `rt`.